# What is the difference between <c:if> and <c:when>?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I've noticed usages of `<c:if ...>` in one place of JSP code and `<c:when ...>` in the other. The things they do look the same for me. Are these two commands just aliases?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`<c:if` is a simple if-clause. `<c:when>` has options for multiple if-clauses and an else clause. Compare:

```
<c:if test="${foo == 'bar'}">...</c:if>
```

with

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${foo == 'bar'}">...</c:when>
   <c:when test="${foo == 'baz'}">...</c:when>
   <c:otherwise>...</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: it's worth noting that once one of the `<c:when>` condition is true then the control exists the `<c:choose>` block (skipping the other `<c:when>` blocks and `<c:otherwise>` block)

Answer (score 28):

`<c:if>` doesn't support any kind of "else" or "else if" functionality. `<c:when>` does. So if you need something analogous to

```
if (some_condition) {
    // ...
}
```

then use `<c:if>`. If you need something analogous to

```
if (some_condition) {
    // ...
} else if (some_other_condition) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

then use `<c:choose>` with `<c:when>` and (optionally) `<c:otherwise>`.